# Can I add multiple tags to a S3 bucket and not an object using put_bucket_tagging?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to check for specific tags on s3 bucket and if not present to add them. What I got to know is I was only able to add one tag at a time to a bucket using AWS Lambda function(python). Is it some kind of policy or can we add more than one tag to a S3 bucket?

P.S. I am not talking about objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PUT` tagging operation on a bucket *sets* the bucket tags to the tagset of keys and values that you specify with the request -- it doesn't *add* the tags you specify.  If there are existing tags on the bucket, those need to be included with your request, or they will be removed when the new tagset is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add multiple tags at the same time.

```
response = bucket_tagging.put(
    Tagging={
        'TagSet': [
            {
                'Key': 'string',
                'Value': 'string'
            },
        ]
    }
)
```

Check this [link](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.BucketTagging.put)

Comment: I have already tried that. My question if there is one tag already present I cant add another with the above code.